# cfmodule with .html files

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

How do I get cfmodule to work with html files

```
Invalid template inc/nav.html provided for CFMODULE tag. 

 CFMODULE tag only supports including ColdFusion templates.   

 The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ColdDoc/strategy/api/resources/templates/overview-summary.html: line 28
Called from C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ColdDoc/strategy/AbstractTemplateStrategy.cfc: line 329
Called from C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ColdDoc/strategy/api/HTMLAPIStrategy.cfc: line 150
Called from C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ColdDoc/strategy/api/HTMLAPIStrategy.cfc: line 35
Called from C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ColdDoc/ColdDoc.cfc: line 37
Called from C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ColdDoc/run.cfm: line 10

26 : <BODY BGCOLOR="white" onload="windowTitle();">
27 : 
28 : <cfmodule template="inc/nav.html"
29 :            page="Overview"
30 :            projectTitle= "#arguments.projectTitle#"
```

This seems to be a change in behavior from Adobe ColdFusion 9

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for this?

Comment: This tool https://github.com/markmandel/ColdDoc is built using cfmodule using html

Comment: Why would you need `cfmodule`? The advantage of `cfmodule` compared to `cfinclude` is the separate context and passing variables in. A static HTML file doesn't need either. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexanderKwaschny - I was thinking something similar, but looking at the the project it exploits the previous ability to use any file type to pass in variables *and* generate java style documentation (typically uses .html files). Not sure how easily it could be refactored to work around the new restriction.

Comment: To clarify, "inc/nav.html" actually contains cfml code.

Comment: I posted a ticket on the site. https://github.com/markmandel/ColdDoc/issues/11 . Maybe it will get fixed

Comment: There is probably a cleaner fix, but the basic doc generation seem to work if you rename all the *.html files in strategy\api\resources\templates as *.cfm. Then replace the .html extension with .cfm inside AbstractTemplateStrategy.cfc writeTemplate(), just before the savecontent call writeTemplate(): `<cfset arguments.template = rereplace( arguments.template , "\.(html|htm)$", ".cfm") >`

Comment: I think that is not just the best answer, I think it is the only answer

Comment: It looks like I was using an older version of the software. It have been forked and update on https://github.com/Ortus-Solutions/DocBox

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Good to hear. Have not used it yet, but it says CF10+, so I assume it resolves the cfmodule issue? (Also good to know the fix was not too far off the mark).  If it works, you should post that as an answer with a note about cfmodule no longer accepting non-cfm in CF11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1**

The short answer is ColdFusion won't do this anymore. `<cfmodule>` is not like `<cfinclude>`. There are no overrides.

**Part 2**

The software package I was using has been updated and is at http://github.com/Ortus-Solutions/DocBox . The new version does not have this issue.

**Part 3**

Like Leigh pointed out, it is posible to write a wrapper and have the wrapper pull in the `.html` files with CFML

Answer (score 4):

I don't have CF11 installed but there were changes made to `<cfinclude>` that only allows one to include .cfm files by default but it can be disabled with `allowedextinclude`.  I am not sure if that will also allow you to use .html for `<cfmodule>`.

See https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/changes-in-coldfusion.html under **Restrictions**

For reference: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/02/coldfusion-11-first-bug-bad-bug.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the docs were not updated. Adam's blog entry mentions they changed the name before release to `compileextforinclude` and apparently added it [as an application setting as well](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html). I tried it with CF11, but it does not seem to have any affect on `<cfmodule>`.

Comment: @Leigh doc were not updated, 'cause it is NO LONGER A WIKI... urgh.  Thanks!

Comment: I just tried out `this.compileextforinclude = "*";` and just like Leigh, it gives the same error message.

Comment: @Henry - I have given up on some aspects of the CF docs ... ;-)

Comment: @Leigh FWIW I just sent them through Feedback -> Not Helpful with the relevant missing info

Comment: I am thinking the answer is "This can't be done". CF 11 won't run cfmodule in this way

Comment: @JamesAMohler - I suspect you are right. Poked around a bit and did not find any options or methods that would allow cfmodule to run a non-.cfm file under CF11.